# Fibre of smooth holomorphic map is manifold (ComGeo by Huybrechts)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I have a question on a remark from Daniel Hyubrechts' Complex Geometry [Complex Geometry](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf)  on page 107.

> **Definition 2.6.13** A holomorphic map $f: X \to Y$ is smooth at a point $x \in X$ if the induced map $\mathcal{T}_X(x) \to  (f^*\mathcal{T}_Y)(x) = \mathcal{T}_Y(f(x))$ is surjective.
>
> As an immediate consequence of Corollary 1.1.12 one finds:
>
> **Corollary 2.6.14** Let $f : X \to Y$ be a holomorphic map and $y \in Y$. Assume
>   that $f$ is smooth in all points of the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$. Then the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth complex submanifold of $X$.

Corollary 1.1.12 tells me that:

> **Corollary 1.1.12** Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^m$ be an open subset and let $f: U \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be a holomorphic map. Assume that $z_0 \in U$ such that 
>    $rank(J(f)(z_0))$ is maximal.
>
> i) If $m>n$ then there exists a biholomorphic map $h : V \to U'$, where $U'$ is
>   an open subset of $U$ containing $z_0$, such that $f(h(z_1,\dots, z_m)) = ( z_1 , \dots , z_n)$
>   for all $(z_1, \dots, z_m) \in V$.
>
> ii) If $m < n$ then there exists a biholomorphic map $g : V \to  V$,
>   where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ containing $f(z_o)$, such that $g(f(z)) =
> ( z_1 , \dots , z_m, 0 , \dots , 0 )$.

Q: I do not understand why Corollary 2.6.14 is a consequence of corollary 1.1.12 and how it is applied to our case. Essentially, 1.1.12 is nothing but the  inverse functions theorem giving criterion on local invertibility in an open neighborhood. As $f$ smooth, we are in case i): $m >n$ as by assumption the differential map is surjective. The fibre $f^{-1}(z_0)$ is in general a closed set. I don't understand how the existence of the biholomorphic map as described above imply that the fibre is a submanifold of $X$. I would be very thankful if somebody could take some time to explain the argument presented in the book.

Comment: Are you familiar with the standard proof from topology that the preimage of a regular value is a manifold?

Comment: the standard proof? possibly do you refer to that one from Milnor's Topology from the Differential Viewpoint on page 11? it is also explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824631/understanding-milnors-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-preimage-of-a-regular-value-is and morally there the Corollary 1.1.12 is applied of auxilary function $F$ described in the linked MSE question. 1.1.12 contribute an open $U \subset M$ and the intersection of fibre $f^{-1}(y)\cap U$ is diffeomorphically to $y \times R^{m-n}$ by construction. is this exactly the argument you proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This terminology is quite nonstandard, such maps are usually called (holomorphic) **submersions.** Corollary 1.1.12 is stronger than the Inverse Mapping Theorem, it is usually called the "Constant Rank Theorem". Once you assume it, then Corollary 2.6.14 is immediate since (by a local biholomorphic change of variables in the domain and the range) the problem reduces to the case when $f: {\mathbb C}^m\to {\mathbb C}^n$ is a surjective linear map $(z_1,...,z_m)\mapsto (z_1,...,z_n)$. The preimage of ${\mathbf 0}$ under such a map is a linear subspace of dimension $m-n$, i.e. a smooth complex submanifold of the expected dimension.

Comment: This terminology is what one might say if one were coming to complex geometry as an algebraic geometer who hadn't taken other geometry classes before - the analogy between a smooth map in the algebraic category and a submersion in the (complex) manifold category is a very standard way to teach folks who know one side the other (though usually one knows about a submersion before they know about a smooth map :P).

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at Lee's book on smooth manifolds, especially the proof of Theorem 8.8 and the references in there. For the complex case you can use the same arguments, the charts you construct are automatically holomorphic, since the implict function theorem yields holomorphic maps in this setting.